# Jquerymobile autodividers using jquery ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using listview in jquerymobile. I have ul tag and i am inserting a list of li through ajax. Now i want to implement auto-divider in listview. How can i do that.

My code is (HTML)

```
<ul id="guestlistview_Guests" class="ul_guestList"
    data-role="listview"     
    data-theme="d">     
</ul>
```

I have tried it. but it did not work

```
 $('#guestlistview_Guests').attr("data-autodividers", true);
 $('#guestlistview_Guests').listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify `data-autodividers = "true"` statically in the HTML code itself. If the list is empty it does not make any difference. Then later after dynamically adding the list items, you could do a `.listview('refresh')` or `.listview('refresh',true)`